# SQL JOIN get details from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables

1. `User_Details`  with columns (`user_id, name`)
2. `Stock_Details`  with columns (`user_id foreign key, stocks`)
3. `Billing_Details` with columns (`user_id foreign key, billing`)

How to display a list of users with their `Stock_Details` and `billing_Details`?

Comment: Are you trying to just show the list of users for which there are stock details and billing details (which appears to be the problem that the first answers appear to solve)? Or are you trying to show the user's name when looking at the stock details and billing details?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you to solve your problem, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the little checkbox below its score. If not, please provide us more details on what isn't working so we can help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.name,
       b.billing,
       s.stocks
FROM user_details u
LEFT JOIN billing_details b on b.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN stock_details s on s.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    T1.user_id,
    T1.name,
    T2.stocks,
    T3.billing
FROM
    User_Details T1 INNER JOIN Stock_Details T2 ON T1.User_id=T2.User_id
        INNER JOIN Billing_Details T3 ON T2.User_id=T3.User_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that record which are either in stock table or in billing table so, Try this ...

```
select <your required fields> 
From User_Details ud inner join Stock_Details sd on ud.user_id=sd.user_id
Union 
select <your required fields> 
From User_Details ud inner join billing_Details bd on ud.user_id=bd.user_id
where ud.user_id not in (select user_id from stock_details)
```

Note: fields are same in both union and same order.. Otherwise it returns error..